# can a windows domain logon include more than 1 '\' char?

Tags: c#, windows, authentication

As per title, can there ever be more than 1 \ char in a windows logon name?

e.g.

```
mydomain\ghostJago
```

Can this ever become `somedomain\mydomain\ghostJago` under any circumstance.

I'm asking as I want to split an incoming userstring in C# on `\` and get exactly 2 elements.

Comment: Note that the logon name might also be `ghostJago@my.domain`, which does not contain any backslashes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not aware that you ever login to a domain of masterdomain\subdomain\user, its always domain\user be aware, of course, some nice thoughtful people will type domain/user

Comment: Some people may also write user@domain.

Comment: ...and others will write *domain@username*. I always marvel at how some people manage to log in to their desktops every morning.

Comment: so it looks like the ultra safe approach is split on \, check if I have 2 elements, if not, split on @.  That should do it

Comment: @Widor: Oh my. That sounds like the `10[a]` of domain login.

Comment: ghostJago, you should test for \, / and @

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so.

I also have applications which rely on the splitting of '\' and have never encountered an issue.